# Создание нового окна в pyqt5, во время выполнения потока в основном окне

Tags: python, pyqt5

У меня есть два окна.

Основное, которое выполняет некую функцию, используя при этом потоки. В определённый момент, основное окно вызывает побочное(окно уведомления). Если я не использую потоки, всё работает в норме, если использую. То окно уведомления появляется на короткий миг, в который оно не доступно, после чего исчезает(также возможно выставить sleep, чтобы проверить это).

**Вопрос**: как организовать вызов второго окна, во время выполнения потоков в первом.

```
def thread(my_func):
    """
    Run function in a different thread
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()
    return wrapper


# Окно уведомлений
class MsgBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MsgBox, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.location_on_the_screen()
        self.setWindowTitle('Сообщение')

        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('', self)
        self.lbl.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.lbl.move(15, 10)
        self.lbl.setText(self.message)

# Основное окно
class Ui_Form(QMainWindow):
    # signal value for thread
    my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list, name='my_signal')

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        # По клику выполняется метод func
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.func(self.my_signal))

        # Обработчик сигнала
        self.my_signal.connect(self.mySignalHandler, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    # Метод создания окна уведомлений
    def create_window(self):
        second_window = MsgBox()
        second_window.show()

    # Метод основной, выполняется с потоками
    @thread
    def func(self,my_signal):
        .......
        self.create_window()
        ......


# Вызов
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Form = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.get_from_config_file()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вызов уведомления не должен быть в отдельном треде. Все окна должны отрисовываться основным потоком. Если вы хотите инициировать показ уведомления из потока, то используйте `QThread` и сигнал, на который подпишется ваш `QMainWindow`.

Comment: я пробовал использование QThread
Побочное окно тем не менее недоступно во время использования основного потока:
https://github.com/leexxg/threads-two-window/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Если побочное окно недоступно, то значит вы блокируете event loop.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а можно ли узреть пример простейшей структуры с 2 окнами(ссылку на него?), в одном из которых исполняется поток и вызывается другое окно. Т.к. перерыл куча примеров с потоками/слотами, не нашёл ничего подобного.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с потоком, который выводит второе окно, как приходит сообщение из потока. При этом не блокируется ни основное окно, ни дополнительное.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class WorkThread(Qt.QThread):
    threadSignal = Qt.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = 0
        while True:
            Qt.QThread.msleep(1000)
            c += 1
            self.threadSignal.emit(c)
        return Qt.QThread.run(self, *args, **kwargs)


class MsgBox(Qt.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = Qt.QLabel("")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        close_btn = Qt.QPushButton("Close")
        close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(close_btn)
        self.resize(50, 50)


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.btn = Qt.QPushButton("Run thread!")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn)
        self.msg = MsgBox()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)
        self.thread = None

    def on_btn(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread()
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.start()
            self.btn.setText("Stop thread")
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.btn.setText("Start thread")

    def on_threadSignal(self, value):
        self.msg.label.setText(str(value))
        if not self.msg.isVisible():
            self.msg.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```